# Assistance with the creation of site offering lists based challenges

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, list, dynamic

I want to develop a website that offers lists based challenges. The idea is based upon the website http://listchallenges.com where users can look at different types of lists and select the options that they have personally done (watched a movie, went to a place, etc.

Here is a part of my code :

```
function ($) {          
$('#ig-thumbs').delegate('img','click', function()
{   
if(record.indexOf($(this).parent().attr('id'))  > -1 )
{
$(this).removeClass("counted");

if(a < 1)
{}
else
{
a=a-1;

document.getElementById("result").value=a;
record.pop($(this).parent().attr('id'),record);
}
}
else
{


record.push($(this).parent().attr('id') ) ;

$(this).addClass("counted") 


a=a+1;
document.getElementById("text").value=a;

}

});
```

This code basically uses the variable a as the counter and displays its value in a text box called "result". "this" refers to a individual image that is being clicked which gets a class "counted" when it is clicked and the class is removed when it is clicked again. All of this is working fine but the problem arises in the dynamic updation of the variable a. Once a image is clicked the value of a increments by 1 but sometimes I have to click on the image twice to decrement the value.

For eg - If their are 8 items and I click on them once the value of a becomes 8 and gets displayed correctly. But when I click on all the images again the value does not become 0 but rather comes down to 1 or 2 and I have to click on the first or second image again to decrement the value to 0.

Can anybody help me in optimizing the code as I have tried many different things but I am unable to get it right.

Comment: `record.pop($(this).parent().attr('id'),record);` see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop  Pop doesn't accept any argument

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="result" >0</div>
<div id = "listImg">
    <a class="cls" href="#"><img src="1.jpg"/></a>
    <a class="cls" href="#"><img src="2.jpg"/></a>
    <a class="cls" href="#"><img src="3.jpg"/></a>
    <a class="cls" href="#"><img src="4.jpg"/></a>
</div>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script>
$(function() {
    var count=0;
    $('.cls').click(function() {
        if($(this).attr("href")=="#"){
            $("#result").html(++count);
            $(this).attr("href","#ok");
        }else{
            $("#result").html(--count);
            $(this).attr("href","#");
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

i hope this code help you :)